# What's the real-space equivalent of the Fermi surface?

Tags: condensed-matter

So I'm familiar with the concept of Fermi surface in momentum space and all that. But if everything in the momentum space can be obtained by Fourier transforming *something* in the real space (e.g. crystal lattice <-> Brillouin zone; point-like electron <-> plane wave), how should I think about the Fermi surface in the real space?

Meaning, if the Fermi surface is a set of crystal momentum *k* with the same Fermi energy, in real space it should be a collection of electron's positions with the same *something*?

Answer (score 1):

In the crystal lattice, free electrons propagate with different wavelengths.  In a given crystal similar wavelengths tend to be either all occupied or all empty.  The Fermi surface physically corresponds to the cut-off wavelengths were states go from occupied to unoccupied or vice-versa.  So in physical space it is crystal-wide (since each electron state of given wavelength extend through the whole crystal), though it is a sharp surface in momentum space.

Ashcroft and Mermin has a good discussion for fermi surfaces with many useful example.  In momentum space they can look rather exotic because it is not necessarily the higher wavelength crystal-wide states that are empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paul. Do you have any reference for this statement?